# Check if optional values contains right characters through Regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am using this regex :

```
egrep "([+][0-9]{2})?[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}([-][0-9]{4})$"
```

so as per my logic, the optional value should be `+` followed by 2 numeric digit => `+54`

but when i am using this, i am getting below output :

```
+11-555-555-5555  #this is correct
+917-999-999-9999  #this is wrong
```

**Question :** Is there some special method to check if `optional` value contains EXACTLY what is mentioned in `regex` or i am using incorrect approach??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^([+][0-9]{2})?[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}([-][0-9]{4})$
```

With caret (`^`), the sequence `+` followed by two digits must be present or not at the beginning of the string.

On the other hand; without caret, what is important is the sequence at the end of the string. The initial sequence is optionnal.

This is why the regex matched incorrectly the second line.

Comment: why wont it match the pattern without `caret -- ^ --`??